# priority queue top() segmentation fault

Tags: c++11, segmentation-fault, priority-queue

I am trying to solve this problem https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-find-the-running-median

I have passed only one test case. I am trying to debug, by printing intermediate values.
In the end, I am trying to print h2.top() (mentioned in code as "problem"), that line is giving segmentation fault. h1.top() is working fine.

I am not understanding why only h2.top() is giving segmentation fault.
If possible can anyone point out the mistake in my program.

```
int main() {

int n, ele;
int temp;
int c = 0;
cin >> n;

priority_queue<int> h1 = priority_queue<int, vector<int>, less<int> >();  //max_heap
priority_queue<int,vector<int>,greater<int> > h2 = priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int> >();  //min_heap

for(int a_i = 0;a_i < n;a_i++) {
   cin >> ele;
    if(h1.empty())
        h1.push(ele);
    else if(ele <= h1.top()) {
        if(h1.size() <= h2.size())
            h1.push(ele);
        else {
            temp = h1.top();
            h1.pop();
            h2.push(temp);
            h1.push(ele);
        }
    }
    else{
        if(h2.size() < h1.size())
            h2.push(ele);
        else {
            temp = h2.top();
            h2.pop();
            h1.push(temp);
            h2.push(ele);
        }
    }    
    c++;
   if(c & 1 == 1) {
        if(h1.size() > h2.size())
            cout<<fixed<<setprecision(1)<<(float)h1.top()<<endl;
        else
            cout<<fixed<<setprecision(1)<<(float)h2.top()<<endl;
    }
    else
        cout<<fixed<<setprecision(1)<<(h1.top()+h2.top())/2.0<<endl;
    cout<<c<<" h1: "<<h1.top()<<"  "<<h1.size();
    cout<<"\n  h2:"<<h2.top()<<"  ";  //problem
    //cout<<h2.top();
    cout<<h2.size()<<"\n\n";
}
//cout<<h1.size();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Most likely, `h1` is not empty and so `h1.top()` works; while `h2` is empty and so `h2.top()` exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: Below that 'h2.size()' outputs non zero. So 'h2' is not empty. @igor

Comment: How can code "below that" output anything at all, when calling `h2.top()` produces a segmentation fault, thereby aborting the execution of the program? In any case, it's clear that, on the first iteration of the loop, one of the queues must be empty; and yet you call `top()` on both, unconditionally.

Comment: The first time through the loop, `h2.size()` will return 0 when you get to that line. So calling `h2.top()` is going to give you an error.

Comment: Oh, got it, thanks